# cannot start microsoft outlook 2016. cannot open the outlook window. the set of folders

Tags: windows, windows-7, exchange, outlook, outlook-2016

I have this one client machine on Windows 7 with a full reinstall of Office, Windows Updates, and scanned/clear.

The moment I add more then one email account to Outlook, close Outlook and bring it up, and close it again, it will never come back up again.

It will keep throwing the following error:

```
cannot start microsoft outlook 2016. cannot open the outlook window. the set of folders...
```

I've been down every list on the first 5 page of Google and need ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue.

The email accounts are Exchange based.

The moment, I remove all the accounts but the original one, it will start up again.

Comment: Search for clearing out Outlook profile from the Registry.  Even though you have uninstalled/reinstalled Office, there's something up with the outlook Profiles. This would be shown in the Mail Control Panel

Comment: Just curious before trying to answer...does the exact same user and Outlook configuration experience the same thing if on another computer?

Comment: Good question. Not sure. I did think about creating a new profile to see if it was profile related but I have not gotten that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook profiles are stored in the Registry, at the following path:

**Office 2013**
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles`

**Office 2016:**
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles`

Assuming you are okay with potential data loss, the delete contents here.  If you need to attempt to recover PST/OST data, export the key data first, and try renaming keys instead.